# Did Eleanor tell Vane about the tunnels beneath the fort?

Tags: plot-explanation, black-sails

I've just finished season 1 of *Black Sails*. In the last episode, when Vane appears, he tells Eleanor to be partners or else he will start sinking ships.

When Eleanor talks with Captain Hornigold he tells her that he can attack Vane with 300 men.

However, Eleanor tells Hornigold that she told Vane about the secret tunnels that Hornigold would use to make a surprise attack to the fort.

I didn't see them speaking about that (Vane and Eleanor). Is Eleanor lying in order to protect Vane from getting killed, or do we have to assume that she talked about the tunnels another time, *before* the incidents?

Comment: From what I watched so far (S02e04) It's "we have to assume that she talked about the tunnels another time"

Comment: Well the **Third** season is Airing. And I just don't want to add a spoiler and get **DOWNVOTES**